# Using samples() with php-ml

Tags: php, php-ml

I am using php-ml and taking in a .csv file with 6 columns and thousands of lines, i want every 5th element (column) of each array to be saved in $samples. I have tried the following which gives me the first element of each array.

```
$dataset = new CsvDataset('myCsvFile.csv', 1);

$samples = [];
foreach ($dataset->getSamples() as $sample) {
    $samples[] = $sample[0];
}
```

However this gives me the first element of each array, if i change the `$sample[0] to $sample[4]` as i thought syntactically this would work i get an Undefined offset on the line in question. I am new to PHP and don't understand why this would happen.

If the code is left as above and printed out it looks like the following:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 1157
    [1] => 1157
    [2] => 1157
    [3] => 1157
    [4] => 1157
    [5] => 1157
    [6] => 1157
    [7] => 1157
    [8] => 1157
```

...and so on.

Comment: Can you put sample data of csv 1 or line here

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service...

Comment: @TomUdding i have edited the question with my attempts

Comment: @johnfish92 the '0' (`$sample[0];`) selects the first column of your CSV file. '1' will select the second column, '2' will select the third column and so on...

Comment: I added your previous code back since you just removed code and replaced it with totally different code.  Maybe you should post what you're actually using.

Comment: @TomUdding I had tried that however it gave me an error message 'undefined offset' therefore i thought it was incorrect syntax with php. Do you know why it throws that error if syntacitcally its correct? Note: it throws this error on that exact line as well.

Comment: @AbraCadaver i have edited the question as leaving the body of code in is getting answers which are not what i need and wasting users time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$csv = array();
$csvNewArray = array();
$lines = file('myCsvFile.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{
    $csv[$key] = str_getcsv($value);
    if(isset($csv[$key][4])){
     $csvNewArray[$key] = $csv[$key][4];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing into `$csv[$key][6]`? He said he wants to store the fifth element into a new array.

Comment: because array has start with 0th element

Comment: Why are you assigning into the same array at all?

Comment: because there is thousands of lines if we made multiple loops than its take  too much time. so i have updated my answer to get 5th element in new array

Comment: You don't need multiple loops. Just `$new_array[] = $csv[$key][4]`

Comment: yes i have also done this. Put the value in new Array Element [UPDATED]. Thanks for notice that

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgetcsv()` to read from the file, then access the appropriate element of these arrays to get the fifth item of each row.

```
$fh = fopen("myCsvFile.csv", "r") or die("Can't open CSV file\n");
$csv = array();
$sample = array();
while ($row = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    $csv[] = $row;
    $sample[] = $row[4];
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: You need to make here array for multiple **$sample[] = $row[4];**